# RHEL 7.9 Help: Why do I get differences between lsblk and df

Tags: filesystems, rhel, disk-usage, lsblk

I have resized recently the `rhel-root` partition of my RHEL 7.9 system, basically I did the following commands:

```
pvresize /dev/sda2
```

```
lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/rhel/root
```

I was able to resize the partition and I can see it if I check the command:
`pvs`
the output is the following:

```
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree

  /dev/sda2  rhel lvm2 a--  <99.00g    0
```

if I check the command:
`lsblk`
the output is the following:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0  100G  0 disk 
├─sda1          8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2          8:2    0   99G  0 part 
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0 98.2G  0 lvm  /
  └─rhel-swap 253:1    0  820M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

So I can see that I have almost 100GB on my sda2 > rhel-root partition, however if I check the command:
`df -h`
the output is the following:

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs               482M     0  482M   0% /dev
tmpfs                  496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  496M  6.9M  489M   2% /run
tmpfs                  496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-root  6.2G  6.2G  1.3M 100% /
/dev/sda1             1014M  172M  843M  17% /boot
shared                 932G  448G  484G  49% /media/shared
tmpfs                  100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user/0
```

do you know why I get this difference in sizes? do I missed some step? both `/dev/rhel/root` and `/dev/mapper/rhel-root` are links to `/dev/dm-0` disk.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Perhaps adding `-r` to your lvextend command would have helped? You created a larger volume but did not tell the file system that it had more space. 'growfs` or its equivalent may help.

Answer (score 0):

You resized only the block device and not the filesystem on it so your LV is 98 GiB but the filesystem still only 6 GiB. Next time when you use `lvresize` don't forget to add the `-r`/`--resizefs` option to resize both the device and the filesystem in one step.

Assuming your system uses XFS (which is default on RHEL, you can check with `lsblk -f`) you can use `xfs_growfs /` to resize the filesystem on the root logical volume to the size of the underlying block device. If you have Ext4 use `resize2fs /dev/rhel/root`.